# Android Jetpack Compose: Ripple effect is not working when using clickable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I used this [example](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#tapping) from android docs:

```
@Composable
fun ClickableSample() {
    val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    // content that you want to make clickable
    Text(
    text = count.value.toString(),
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { count.value += 1 }
    )
}
```

This is how I'm using it in my App:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Lemon_treeTheme {
                ClickableSample()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ripple effect is not working as expected. I tried applying the clickable modifier to various elements such as Box and Row but it's not working as well. It works only with clickable elements such as Button. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ripple is clipped by **the bounds of the target layout**, then the size of the composable can influence the ripple appearance.

You can override it specifying a custom indication with `bounded = false`:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Text(
    text = count.value.toString(),
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false)
        ) { count.value += 1 }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Now it works, but why the docs says nothing about this? It says It should work with the provided example.

Comment: @ameencarpenter It depends on the size of the text. If you assign a size modifier it can work also with the default value